# How many numbers $k$ of $200 \choose k$ are divisible by $3$? $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots 200\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

"How many of the numbers $200 \choose k$, where $k$ is an element of the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,....,200\}$, are divisible by $3$?"

Here is my thinking:

$200 \choose 0$, $200 \choose 1$, $200 \choose 2$ are not multiples of $3$ but every next combination has at least $1$ multiple of $3$ in the numerator therefore making the number divisible by $3$. Since there are $201$ numbers from $0$ to $200$, and $3$ numbers ($0,1,$ and $2$) do not work, there are $198$ numbers $k$.

Is this the right answer and is this the right method?

Comment: If $k=9n+r$ , with $r\in\{0,1,2\}$ , then $200\choose k$ does NOT divide through $3$.

Comment: You must also consider the factors of $3$ in the denominator. $\binom{200}9$ is not divisible by $3$. It’s equal to $$\frac{200\cdot199\cdot\ldots\cdot192}{9!}\;,$$ where the multiples of $3$ in the numerator are $198,195$, and $192$, while those in the denominator are $9,6$, and $3$. There are $4$ factors of $3$ in each, so there are no factors of $3$ in the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Where did you get $k = 9n+r$ from?

Comment: Using J I get that there are 36 $k$'s for which $\binom{200}{k}$ is not divisible by 3. They are: ``0 1 2 9 10 11 27 28 29 36 37 38 81 82 83 90 91 92 108 109 110 117 118 119 162 163 164 171 172 173 189 190 191 198 199 200``. I used these lines of code (respectively): ``201-+/0=3|!&200x i.201`` and ``(#~(-.@(0&=)@(3&|)@(!&200x))) i.201``.

Comment: Those calculations confirm @Lucian statement.

Comment: Also, I forgot to add that $n=9p+q$ , where $q\in\{0,1,3,4\}$ .

Answer (score 3):

According to [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem), a binomial coefficient $\binom{m}{n}$ is divisible by a prime *p* if and only if at least one of the base *p* digits of *n* is greater than the corresponding digit of *m*.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\dcc}[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}$ We know from Legendre's theorem that the power of a prime $p$ in $n!$ is equal to $\sum_{a=1}^\infty \dcc{\frac{n}{p^a}}$. See, for example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Number_theory), [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicity_of_Prime_Factor_in_Factorial); you can easily find many [online resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=legendre+factorial+prime)
and [books](http://books.google.com/books?q=legendre+factorial+prime) where this result is explained.

We are interested in the power in which the prime 3 appears in the number $\binom{200}k=\frac{200!}{(200-k)!k!}$.

The multiplicity of 3 in 200! is
$$\dcc{\frac{200}3}+\dcc{\frac{200}9}+\dcc{\frac{200}{27}}+\dcc{\frac{200}{81}}.$$
We want to compare this number with
$$\dcc{\frac{200-k}3}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}9}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}{27}}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}{81}}
+\dcc{\frac{k}3}+\dcc{\frac{k}9}+\dcc{\frac{k}{27}}+\dcc{\frac{k}{81}},$$
which is the multiplicity in which $3$ appears in $(200-k)!k!$.

Since $\dcc a +\dcc b\le\dcc{a+b}$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\dcc{\frac{k}3}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}3} &\le \dcc{\frac{200}3}\\
\dcc{\frac{k}9}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}9} &\le \dcc{\frac{200}9}\\
\dcc{\frac{k}{27}}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}{27}} &\le \dcc{\frac{200}{27}}\\
\dcc{\frac{k}{81}}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}{81}} &\le \dcc{\frac{200}{81}}
\end{align*}
$$
We want to find the values of $k$ for which at least one of these inequalities are strict.

It is useful to notice that the value $\dcc{\frac{k}3}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}3}$ is the same for all $k$'s in the same residue class modulo 3. So it suffices to check $k=0,1,2$ and we see that 
$$\dcc{\frac{k}3}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}3} = \dcc{\frac{198}3} = \dcc{\frac{200}3}$$
for any $k$. (We tried $k\equiv 0,1,2\pmod3$).

For 9 we get
$$\dcc{\frac{k}9}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}9}=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{198}9=22=\dcc{\frac{200}9} & \text{for }k\equiv0,1,2 \pmod9, \\
    \frac{191}9=21<\dcc{\frac{200}9} & \text{for }k\equiv3,4,\dots,8 \pmod9
  \end{cases}
$$

For 27 we get
$$\dcc{\frac{k}{27}}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}{27}}=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{189}{27}=7=\dcc{\frac{200}{27}} & \text{for }k\equiv0,1,2,\dots,11 \pmod{27}, \\
    \frac{162}{27}=6<\dcc{\frac{200}{27}} & \text{for }k\equiv12,13,\dots,26 \pmod{27}
  \end{cases}
$$

For 81 we get
$$\dcc{\frac{k}{81}}+\dcc{\frac{200-k}{81}}=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{162}{81}=2=\dcc{\frac{200}{81}} & \text{for }k\equiv0,1,2,\dots,38 \pmod{81}, \\
    \frac{81}{81}=1<\dcc{\frac{200}{81}} & \text{for }k\equiv39,\dots,80 \pmod{81}
  \end{cases}
$$

So the numbers which $k$ for which $\binom{200}k$ is **not** divisible by $3$ are precisely the numbers which simultaneously fulfill the conditions
$$
\begin{align*}
k&\equiv0,1,2 \pmod9\\
k&\equiv0,1,2,\dots,11 \pmod{27}\\
k&\equiv0,1,2,\dots,38 \pmod{81}
\end{align*}
$$
The first two conditions are fulfilled if $k\equiv0,1,2,9,10,11\pmod{27}$. If we add the third condition, we get that this holds for
$$ k \equiv 0,1,2,9,10,11,27,28,29,36,37,38 \pmod{81}$$
This gives us the 36 possible values $k=
0,1,2,9,10,11,
27,28,29,36,37,38,
81,82,83,90,91,92,
108,109,110,117,118,119,
162,163,164,171,172,173,
189,190,191,198,199,200$.

This coincides with the calculations mentioned in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597334/how-many-numbers-k-of-200-choose-k-are-divisible-by-3-k-in-0-1-2-cd/597344#comment1258673_597334).

Answer (score 0):

See for example N. J. Fine, Binomial coefficients modulo a prime, Am. Math. Monthly 54 (10) (1947) 589-592, http://www.jstor.org/stable/2304500 .
See also D. Singmaster, Divisibility of binomial and multinomial coefficients by primes and prime powers, http://www.fq.math.ca/Books/Collection/singmaster.pdf .